# Transform JSON into jbuilder syntax with key having colon in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I am trying to transform my JSON object to jbuilder syntax but the JSON itself contains colon character in it's key.
My JSON looks like this:

```
style: {
  "ui:className": "custom-class"
}
```

I am trying this:

```
json.style do
   json.ui:className "custom-class"
end
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end json.ui:className "custom-class" ^ schema.json.jbuilder:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`key_format!`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/Jbuilder:key_format!) method :

```
json.style do
  json.key_format! -> (key) { (key == "ui_className") ? "ui:className" : key }
  json.ui_className "custom-class"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably solve this in one of two ways (if you don't want to transform your key).

1. Send the method name genericly using [*Object#public_send*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

   ```
   json.style do
     json.public_send 'ui:className', 'custom-class'
   end
   ```
2. Use [*JBuilder#merge!*](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/Jbuilder:merge!) to merge the attribute:

   ```
   json.style do
     json.merge! 'ui:className' => 'custom-class'
     # or
     json.merge! 'ui:className': 'custom-class'
   end
   ```